# boost resume thread on mutex unlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

In my application I have a Calculator Thread and a Main_Thread. Both work on the same data. The calculator thread makes precalculations and the main thread visualized the generated data. To prevent that they change and read the data at the same time, I use boost mutex for my critical sections.

```
boost::recursive_mutex m_guard_calculation;
```

Calculator Thread:

```
m_guard_calculation.lock();
// do hard calculation work
m_guard_calculation.unlock();
```

Main Thread:

```
void update() //called every frame
{
    if (m_guard_calculation.try_lock()) //only visualize if not locked, otherwise just skip
    {
        // do hard visualization work
        m_guard_calculation.unlock();
    }
}
```

in that scenario my calculator thread will stop working at some point.
I assume that I have to wake up my calculator thread somehow. How would I do that?

Comment: I would think that 'hard visualization work' exited if scope without onlocking

Comment: thats the wanted behavior. The main thread should not wait if the calculation is busy. My problem is that the calculation thread stops, I assume comes to a deadlock?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to deadlock if you have a single mutex. Looks, like you could use `boost::condition_variable` and wait on `boost::unique_lock` for wakeup. Why are you locking manually anyway?

Comment: whats the not manual solution?

Comment: Oops, I meant using bare locks instead of guards such as `boost::unique_lock` and `boost::lock_guard`.

Comment: okey, fine. Seems to solve my issue. But why would I use std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex); and not only mutex.lock?

Comment: @Anthea It's called RAII and is the only (reasonable) way to have exception safe code and guaranteed unlocking